# How do I do LDA with trigrams in R?

Tags: r, nlp, lda

I am trying to utilize LDA with trigrams instead of single words. I am essentially treating a trigram as a single word. I have to following code below.

```
MD_notes_phrases <- MD_notes %>%
group_by(status) %>%
unnest_tokens(trigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 3) %>%
separate(trigram, c("word1", "word2", "word3"), sep = " ") %>%
filter(!word1 %in% stop_words$word,
       !word1 %in% removedWords$word,
       !word2 %in% stop_words$word,
       !word2 %in% removedWords$word,
       !word3 %in% stop_words$word,
       !word3 %in% removedWords$word) %>%
mutate(phrase = paste(word1,word2,word3,sep = " "))
DTM <- MD_notes_phrases %>%
  cast_dtm(document = status,term = phrase,n)
```

However, when I attempt to create the document term matrix with the cast_dtm function, I get the following error:

```
Error in .M.kind(x) : not yet implemented for matrix with typeof NULL
```

Any help is appreciated. I apologize ahead of time if this is a methodology issue and not a code issue.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example, including some of your original data?